# How to scrape HTML rendered by JavaScript

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I need to write an automated scraper that can take care of websites that are rendered by JavaScript (like YouTube) or just simply use some JavaScript somewhere in their HTML to generate some content (like generating copyright year) and therefore downloading their HTML source make no sense as it won't be the final code (with what users will see).

I use Python with Selenium and WebDriver, so that I can execute JavaScript on a given website. My code for that purpose is:

```
def execute_javascript_on_website(self, js_command):
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options = self.webdriver_options, executable_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/executables/geckodriver')
   driver.get(self.url)

  try:
     return driver.execute_script(js_command)

  except Exception as exception_message:
     pass

  finally:
     driver.close()
```

Where `js_command = "return document.documentElement.outerHTML;"`.

By this code I'm able to get the source code, but not the rendered one. I can do `js_command = "return document;"` (as I would do in console), but than I will get `<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="5a784804-f623-3041-9840-03f13ce83f53", element="585b43a1-f3b2-1e4a-b348-4ddaf2944550")>` object that has the HTML but it's not possible to get it out of it.

Does anyone know about the way how to get HTML rendered by JavaScript (ideally in form of string), using Selenium? Or some other technique that would do it?

PS.: I also tried WebDriver wait, but it didn’t help, I still got HTML with unredered JavaScript.

PPS.: I need to get whole HTML code (whole html tag) with JavaScript rendered in it (as it is for example when inspecting in browsers inspector). Or at least to get DOM of the website in which JavaScript is already rendered.

Comment: I suspect you want to scrape with a scraper, not scrap with a scrapper.

Comment: Oh yes, a typo thanks.

Comment: access the element using selenium methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked into it and I have to admit that JavaScript in @Rumpelstiltskin Koriat's answer works. The current year is present in the returned HTML string, it's placed after the script tag (that as @pguardiario mentioned it has to be there, as it's just HTML tag). I've also found out that in this case of simple JavaScript code from script tags, the WebriverWait is not even needed to obtain the HTML string with a rendered JavaScript code. Apparently I've somehow manged to overlook the rendered by JavaScript string I was so eagerly looking for.

What I've also found (as @Corey Goldberg suggested) is that Selenium methods also works well, while looking better than pure JavaScript line: `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('innerHTML')`. It then returns a string and not any webelement.

On the other hand, when there is a need to scrape a whole HTML of the Angular powered website, it's necessary to locate ideally (at least in the case of YouTube website) it's tag with `id="content"` (and then include this locating at the beginning of all XPaths used later in the code - simulating that we have a whole HTML) or some tag inside this one. WebriverWait was also not needed here as well.
But when locating just HTML tag or *yt-app* tag or any other tag outside of the one with `id="content"` an HTML with unrendered JavaScript is returned then. HTML in the Angular generated websites is mixed with Agular's own tags (that browsers apparently ignores).

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
```

Comment: No (don't know if I'm doing something wrong), this still returns unrendered HTML. I mean that when I execute the code with this JS line I still get the string that has inside `<div>Copyright © 2000-<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script></div>` instead of just the computed year.

Comment: can you share the url you're trying to scrape?

Comment: It’s either https://www.macrumors.com or https://youtube.com. Ideally I would need it to be working for both adresses.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: That script will be there because it's part of the DOM. If the script added something to the DOM, that thing will be there too.

Comment: And yet what is computed by that script is not there. There should be 2018 written there, but it’s not (when executed with a script in the answer).